# Enter container inside VM with gcloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-os

Consider a container optimized VM in a Google Cloud Platform environment.

One can enter the VM:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh __machine__
```

To enter the running container, this is getting more tricky:

```sh
CONTAINER=`gcloud compute ssh __machine__ --command 'docker ps -q | head -1'`
gcloud compute ssh machine --container $CONTAINER
```

This is already ugly enough and in comparison to entering the container with `docker exec -it bash`, this starts with `sh` instead of `bash`.

Is there a way to simplify the command above and to launch `bash` by default?

Comment: Just use `ssh` instead of `gcloud compute ssh`. `gcloud` is executing `ssh` in the background for you. Basically just a wrapper except for the SSH key part. That is the only idea I have to shorten the command.

Comment: Executing ssh directly won't prepare the necessary ssh keys.

Comment: The keys are already on your system now. The CLI stores them in `~/.ssh/`. Also, you can generate your own keys and setup ssh to use `~/.ssh/config`. That would shorten the connect cmd to `ssh hostname`.

Comment: *@Vojtěch* I think *@John Hanley* is right, and this is the only way to shorten the command.

Comment: 1. How can you SSH into a VM without public IP address and is completely hidden by firewall?

Comment: 2. I basically don't need any shortening, I would like to have a single command with which I will be able to enter container running inside gcloud vm instance.

Comment: *@Vojtěch* 1. you can use IAP to access your VM completely hidden by firewall. 2. does you command work for you?